# Write multiple lists to text file in python - 2.7

Tags: python, text, writefile

originally the lists was nested within another list.  each element in the list was a series of strings.

```
['aaa664847', 'Completed', 'location', 'mode', '2014-xx-ddT20:00:00.000']
```

I joined the strings within the list and then append to results.

```
results.append[orginal] 

print results

['aaa664847, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT20:00:00.000']
['aaa665487, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT19:00:00.000']
['aaa661965, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT18:00:00.000']
['aaa669696, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT17:00:00.000']
['aaa665376, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT16:00:00.000']
```

I am looking to write each list to a text file. The number of lists can vary.

My current code:

```
fullpath = ('O:/Location/complete.txt')
outfile = open(fullpath, 'w')
outfile.writelines(results)
```

returns only the first list in the text file:

```
aaa664847, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT20:00:00.000
```

I would like the text file to include all results

Comment: What is "results"? i.e. if you enter: type(results), what do you get back? it looks like "results" is a list with a single string in it, and you've printed 4 different results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `results` is a list of lists:

```
from itertools import chain
outfile = open(fullpath, 'w')
outfile.writelines(chain(*results))
```

[`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) will concat the lists into a single list.
But [`writelines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines) will not write newlines. For that you can do this:

```
outfile.write("\n".join(chain(*results))
```

Or, plainly (assuming all list inside results have only one string):

```
outfile.write("\n".join(i[0] for i in results)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your list is a nested list, you can just use loop to writelines, like this way:

```
fullpath = ('./data.txt')
outfile = open(fullpath, 'w')
results = [['aaa664847, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT20:00:00.000'],
['aaa665487, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT19:00:00.000'],
['aaa661965, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT18:00:00.000'],
['aaa669696, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT17:00:00.000'],
['aaa665376, Completed, location, mode, 2014-xx-ddT16:00:00.000']]

for result in results:
  outfile.writelines(result)
  outfile.write('\n')

outfile.close()
```

Besides, remember close the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you can gather all those strings into a single big list, you could loop through them.

I'm not sure where `results` came from from your code, but if you can put all those strings in a single big list (maybe called masterList), then you could do:

```
fullpath = ('O:/Location/complete.txt')
outfile = open(fullpath, 'w')

for item in masterList:
    outfile.writelines(item)
```

Comment: @zoosuck is right to add the "\n" to separate lines, and close the file when done.